# Transforming Json to Dataframe in Python, pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I was able to get data from an API but I am having trouble making a dataframe out of it.

| id | resultJson |
| --- | --- |
| 63 | "{""Simple Fields"":[{""NumFatura"":""FT 2021FT9/4"" , ... |
| .. | ... |

I'm not able to transform the Json column into multiple columns.
As you can see below, Json also has associated lines which makes the process even more complicated for me

```
,id,resultJson
0,63,"{""Simple Fields"":[{""NumFatura"":""FT 2021FT9/4"",""Data"":""2021-07-28"",""NIF"":""510727069"",""Fornecedor"":null,""ValorTotal"":""3049.17"",""ValorLiquido"":""2479.00"",""ValorIva"":""570.17"",""Linhas"":""table""}],""Simple Fields - Formatted"":[{""NumFatura"":""FT 2021FT9/4"",""Data"":""2021-07-28"",""NIF"":""510727069.00"",""Fornecedor"":null,""ValorTotal"":""3049.17"",""ValorLiquido"":""2479.00"",""ValorIva"":""570.17"",""Linhas"":""table""}],""Linhas"":[{""DescricaoLinha"":""PHC CS DOCUMENTOS + BPM extranet web"",""QuantidadeLinha"":""1.000"",""PrecoUnidadeLinha"":""2121.000"",""DescontoLinha"":""0.00"",""IvaLinha"":""23"",""TotalLiquidoLinha"":""2121.00""},{""DescricaoLinha"":""PHC CS Assinatura Qualificada"",""QuantidadeLinha"":""2.000"",""PrecoUnidadeLinha"":""179.000"",""DescontoLinha"":""0.00"",""IvaLinha"":""23"",""TotalLiquidoLinha"":""358.00""}],""Linhas - Formatted"":[{""DescricaoLinha"":""PHC CS DOCUMENTOS + BPM extranet web"",""QuantidadeLinha"":""Key,Value\r\n\""Value\"",\""\"""",""PrecoUnidadeLinha"":""Key,Value\r\n\""Value\"",\""\"""",""DescontoLinha"":"".00"",""IvaLinha"":""23.00"",""TotalLiquidoLinha"":""2121.00""},{""DescricaoLinha"":""PHC CS Assinatura Qualificada"",""QuantidadeLinha"":""Key,Value\r\n\""Value\"",\""\"""",""PrecoUnidadeLinha"":""Key,Value\r\n\""Value\"",\""\"""",""DescontoLinha"":"".00"",""IvaLinha"":""23.00"",""TotalLiquidoLinha"":""358.00""}]}"
```

I just need the "Simple Fields" and "Linhas"

This was the output that I want:

| id | NumFatura | Data | ... | DescricaoLinha (first field of the rows) | QuantidadeLinha | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | FT 2021FT9/4 | 2021-07-28 | ... | PHC CS DOCUMENTOS + BPM extranet web | 1.000 | ... |
| 63 | FT 2021FT9/4 | 2021-07-28 | ... | PHC CS Assinatura Qualificada | 2.000 | ... |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Is this possible? Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

[output table that i need for those who cant see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZIjB.png)

Edit 1

{'id': 63, 'document': None, 'type': 'data:application/pdf;base64', 'name': 'CPV_88_MELIT FT 2021FT9_4 - 28.07.2021.pdf', 'state': 'Parcial', 'date': None, 'documentId': 0, 'resultJson': '{"Simple Fields":[{"NumFatura":"FT 2021FT9/4","Data":"2021-07-28","NIF":"510727069","Fornecedor":null,"ValorTotal":"3049.17","ValorLiquido":"2479.00","ValorIva":"570.17","Linhas":"table"}],"Simple Fields - Formatted":[{"NumFatura":"FT 2021FT9/4","Data":"2021-07-28","NIF":"510727069.00","Fornecedor":null,"ValorTotal":"3049.17","ValorLiquido":"2479.00","ValorIva":"570.17","Linhas":"table"}],"Linhas":[{"DescricaoLinha":"PHC CS DOCUMENTOS + BPM extranet web","QuantidadeLinha":"1.000","PrecoUnidadeLinha":"2121.000","DescontoLinha":"0.00","IvaLinha":"23","TotalLiquidoLinha":"2121.00"},{"DescricaoLinha":"PHC CS Assinatura Qualificada","QuantidadeLinha":"2.000","PrecoUnidadeLinha":"179.000","DescontoLinha":"0.00","IvaLinha":"23","TotalLiquidoLinha":"358.00"}],"Linhas - Formatted":[{"DescricaoLinha":"PHC CS DOCUMENTOS + BPM extranet web","QuantidadeLinha":"Key,Value\r\n\"Value\",\"\"","PrecoUnidadeLinha":"Key,Value\r\n\"Value\",\"\"","DescontoLinha":".00","IvaLinha":"23.00","TotalLiquidoLinha":"2121.00"},{"DescricaoLinha":"PHC CS Assinatura Qualificada","QuantidadeLinha":"Key,Value\r\n\"Value\",\"\"","PrecoUnidadeLinha":"Key,Value\r\n\"Value\",\"\"","DescontoLinha":".00","IvaLinha":"23.00","TotalLiquidoLinha":"358.00"}]}', 'successPercentage': 0.856569426400321, 'taxonomy': 'Fatura', 'createdBy': 175, 'createdByName': 'geral@multisector.pt', 'createdOn': '2022-09-13T18:13:47.533', 'companyId': 1040, 'errorMessage': 'Missing or Invalid extracted data'}

Comment: `pandas.read_json` for the json string and then add the id column?

Comment: Could you please include a valid json string in your question. If I copy/paste it, I cant read it since the format breaks somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @bitflip i just include the json tring I get from the API.